# Google Maps API quality lower than Google Maps Consumer quality

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are using the Google Maps API on our web application. The map quality that is returned via the API is different than the quality of the map that is returned when using the standard Google Maps application. Is there a setting that needs to be configured as part of the API to ensure the same quality of map is returned?

This is an example of what I am referring to. https://www.google.com/maps/@-26.2514667,28.1114895,37m/data=!3m1!1e3

Good Quality

[image]

This is great quality, but the same location opened via the API has very low quality maps.

Poor Quality

[image]

Comment: They are different products.  Usually the tiles eventually become the same.  How are you accessing the map with the API?  (can't really tell from your pictures, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue with your code) Might you be limiting the zoom?

Comment: The tiles might eventually become the same but there are other aspects of Google Maps website that will (most likely) never make it to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the responses. I have received some feedback (below) from Google's tech support. Will have to accept this for now.

"Hi George,

Thank you for contacting Google Maps Platform technical support. My name is 'redacted' and I'll be helping you today with your issue.

Please note that maps.google.com and Google Maps API are two different products. The imagery used in Static Maps, JS API and the mobile APIs may differ from each other, as well as Google Maps. Google Maps is specialized to use 3D imagery and 2D where not available, as it is optimized using WebGL. The Javascript API uses only 2D imagery.

With that said, to answer your question, there is no setting to ensure that same quality of map is returned. We do continuously update our global imagery.
"